# I'm having a problem using react-native-change-icon

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am currently trying to change the app icon programmatically. I'm using the react-native-change-icon package(v3.1.1). I make the set up and everything, and when i try to change the app icon, i just get a boolean value of true. Then nothing happens, the app icon doesn't change. My current react native version is 0.67.4

Comment: Why Programatically , when you can change manually .

Comment: The problem was fixed. It needed an extra config for it to work on Ipad.